# SQLite Select...Where statement "no such column" error

Tags: sqlite

I have the following SQLite statement:

```
"SELECT * FROM HISTORICALPICKS WHERE BETTYPE = " + betType.ToString().ToUpper() + " ORDER BY DATETIME ASC"
```

And betType.ToString().ToUpper() is the string "ATS"

For some reason I get the following error:

```
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException : SQL logic error or missing database
no such column: ATS
```

...which leaves me baffled. ATS is not a column. BETTYPE is the column. I want it to select rows that have "ATS" in the BETTYPE column.

My hunch is that something is wrong with the syntax. Here is a picture showing the table name and column name, along with a highlight of the value ATS:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need single quotes around the value.

```
"SELECT * FROM HISTORICALPICKS WHERE BETTYPE = '" + betType.ToString().ToUpper() + "' ORDER BY DATETIME ASC"
```