# why does SQLite give a no such column error?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Logcat:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: kelime (code
>   1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM Mylist WHERE Name = kelime

but my column is not 'kelime', it is 'Name'.

My database

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS \"Words\" (\n" +
                "\t\"Id\"\tINTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,\n" +
                "\t\"Name\"\tTEXT,\n" +
                "\t\"Mean\"\tTEXT\n" +
                ");");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS \"MyList\" (\n" +
                "\t\"Id\"\tINTEGER NOT NULL,\n" +
                "\t\"Name\"\tTEXT,\n" +
                "\t\"Mean\"\tTEXT,\n" +
                "\tFOREIGN KEY(\"Id\") REFERENCES \"Words\"(\"Id\"),\n" +
                "\tPRIMARY KEY(\"Id\")\n" +
                ");");


    }
```

```java
public Word FindWord(DbConnection data, String kelime, SQLiteDatabase db){

        Word w= null;

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Words WHERE Name = kelime",null);


        while (c.moveToNext()){
            w = new Word(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Id"))
                    ,c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Name"))
                    ,c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Mean")));

        }

        return w;
    }
    public Boolean ifExists (DbConnection data, String kelime, SQLiteDatabase db) {

        Word w= new Word();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Mylist WHERE Name = kelime",null);


        while (c.moveToNext()){
            w = new Word(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Id"))
                    ,c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Name"))
                    ,c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Mean")));

        }

        if(w!=null) return true;
        else return false;
    }
```

Comment: `kelime` this is a TEXT, it should be `'kelime'`

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42868904/sqlite-select-where-statement-no-such-column-error

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Words WHERE Name = '" + kelime + "'", null);
db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Mylist WHERE Name = '" + kelime + "'", null);
```

Instead of

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Words WHERE Name = kelime",null);
db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Mylist WHERE Name = kelime",null);
```

Comment: @Kestane, Have you checked this?

Answer (score 0):

> why does SQLite give a no such column error?

because you are telling it to get rows from the mylist table where the **name** column = the **kelime** column, and of course there is no such column.

What you are very likely trying to do is **select** rows from the **mylist** table **where** the ***column*** named  **name** has a ***value*** that equals the value ***kelime***. If you are specificying a value rather than a name and that value is not a numeric then you have to tell sqlite what type of value. In the case of a string (TEXT) then you do this be enclosing it in single quotes.

As such you want the query to be :-

```
SELECT * FROM Mylist WHERE Name = 'kelime'
```

The rawQuery method has a second parameter that correctly encloses (binds) such values. So instead of null you pass the values as a string array. Each element will replace a ? in the query on a 1 per 1 basis. This method is recommended as it also offers protection against SQL Injection.

As such you could use :-

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Words WHERE Name = ?",new String[]{"kelime"});
```

- although you could use `Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Words WHERE Name = 'kelime'",null);` this is not recommended, due to it being potentially subject to SQL injection.

There are also convenience methods. They are convenient because they not only correctly enclose (escape) values, they also build the SQL and offer protection against SQL Injection.

As such you could use :-

```
Cursor c = db.query("Words",null,"Name=?", new String[]{"kelime"},null,null,null);
```